# Potentially harmful software detected in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

I have a program (a so-called 'packed program') which is continually falsely flagged as harmful software by windows 10. I have allowed this software in windows defender, and added an exception for the folder that the program is in. However, windows keeps nagging me about this every 10 minutes.

Is there any way to avoid these notifications without disabling windows defender?

Comment: I don't know about the notifications.  If you downloaded it from someplace other than the original provider, it might be a trojan - the original desirable program wrapped inside something else that quietly takes over your PC.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I know (and appreciate your concerns) but this is not the case.

Comment: Add an exception for the file (and/or the folder it's located in) to Windows Defender.